# How can you have a navbar split button dropdown component in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap (v2) and I see from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns that you can have "Split Button Dropdowns".

In the Navbar you can have dropdowns

However it doesn't look like you can have a split dropdown in the navbar.  What I want to use this for is to have the name of the logged in user with the caret next to it. Clicking the user name takes you to a page for the user, but the caret would show a dropdown with actions like "sign out" etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is what I mean. The top bar the caret and button are separate, in the bottom one I use a "normal" button. 

http://jsfiddle.net/musmuris/R3JKz/10/

Neither of these look quite right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navbar split button dropdown with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539329/navbar-split-button-dropdown-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: I don't see how a question asked a year later can be a duplicate? however I've edited to point out this was bootstrap v2 at the time of asking ~4 years ago!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your jsfiddle to do what I *think* you are asking. Putting the caret in its own list item creates that awkward space between the caret and the username.  Overcoming this will require some overrides.  Edit:  As a quick example, I used two classes to remove the padding between the two elements. I had to use the `!important` property though, which is not best practice.
http://jsfiddle.net/R3JKz/15/

```
<li>
 <a href="#" class="caret-before">
  someuser
 </a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">    
 <a class="dropdown-toggle caret-after" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <b class="caret"></b>
 </a>
    ...
 </li>
```

Also included in the jsfiddle is an example of how to use the b tag as the trigger, but this method doesn't work well in the bootstrap navbars because it breaks the layout. Example:

```
<li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#" class="pull-left">
  A Dropdown Menu
 </a>
 <b class="caret pull-left dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 </b>
```

I hope this helped, don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks. Yes - that's what I wanted. I'd come to the same conclusion about padding and tried the same.  Problem with that is the caret doesn't change colour when you hover over the bit it's in - may need a little JS to fix that.  I was hoping bootstrap would have this built in and I'd just missed it. Oh well. Thanks again.

Comment: This has one major disadvantage: On small screens the caret will be displayed as a own menu item instead of being "tied" to the user item.