# Bootstrap Navigation - Is there a way to have the parent clickable instead of just a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation set up where I have a parent element and 3 children, the parent has content as do the three children. In bootstrap 3 however I can't access the parent because of the data-toggle for the children. I have it set to hover instead of click already for computer use which changes to the click for mobile use. Without breaking the mobile click on touch devices is there a way to make the parent element navigate to it's page? I've searched around but everything is either in PHP or the questions go un-answered.

This is the code I have for the navigation:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/home">Home</a> </li>
  <li><a class="cms menulink" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/about">About</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/about/who-we-are">Who we are</a> </li>
      <li><a href="/about/identity-mission">Identity Mission </a> </li>
      <li><a href="/about/origins">Origins</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking to either do this with just html/css or javascript/jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Then, use your js code instead of searching bootstrap js!

Comment: By what I understand, you want something like this-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20539329/navbar-split-button-dropdown-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - no idea what you mean, doesn't help me at all

Comment: @stripathi - that looks like it would work, thanks :D

Comment: Glad it helped. Otherwise, for same look and feel, I was going to suggest a regular button and a no text dropdown next to it.